# How to add jar Non-osgi jar files as dependency to eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle, tycho

I am developing an eclipse plugin using tycho build ,It needs some non-osgi jar files as dependency.when I add the dependency in my pom file ,It does not take the dependency during maven build.
  So, I have tried to make a osgi bundle which contains all the required dependencies by using the following Plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>Osgi-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>Osgi-dependency</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>com.foo.bundle</Private-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.foo.bundle.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>

                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Directory>target/dependency</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-StripGroup>true</Embed-StripGroup>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

After that i have provided the dependency of this osgi bundle to the eclipse plugin .But still it does not take the dependency.
  I have gone through lot of sites.But I am not able to get the solution for this maven build in continuous integration
  But,When I tried creating new plugin project with existing jar and add the osgi bundle and export the plugin .Its work fine. But I am in need to maven continuous builds.
   Please provide some solution to add the dependency to eclipse plugin project.

Comment: Are you building the OSGi wrapper in a separate build? See [this wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts) for more information.

Comment: yea i have tried the way.But it doesnot work. Now i have used p2-maven-plugin to generate the repository and  i have set the repository as target definition and added the required bundles... but now eclipse maven building is working but plugin is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating p2 repository and deployed it in the server.I have created a target definition file and linked it to my plugin project.

We can convert non osgi jars to p2 repository by using the following code.

```
     <build>
        <plugins>
         <plugin>
         <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
    <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-cli</id>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <!-- specify your depencies here -->
            <!-- groupId:artifactId:version -->
            <artifact>
              <id>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.10</id>
            </artifact>
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

'

For detailed information this site is very helpfull.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#convertjars

Answer (score 2):

One possible option is to download jars into separate folder using [maven-dependency-plugin](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker/blob/master/plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.freemarker/pom.xml#L21), [configure classpath in manifest](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker/blob/master/plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.freemarker/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L24) for OSGi bundle and [do not forget to include jars in build](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-freemarker/blob/master/plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.freemarker/build.properties#L9).