# Eclipse PDE, How to access and use external Jar Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, pde

I'm developing a plugin for Eclipse. It is dependent on Appium which in turn, is dependent on the Selenium-API. I have Appium's java_client-3.3.0.jar in the /lib folder of my package and I've added it to the classpath using the runtime view in plugin.xml and so Eclipse no longer complains about Appium imports in my source.

My problem is that is I'm still getting complaints from Eclipse about Selenium imports in my source. When I added the Selenium-api.jar to my classpath I got a conflict. How can I resolve this conflict or better still access the Selenium_api via the Appium jar? Maven normally takes care of all this but it doesn't play nice with PDE. Any all feedback greatly appreciated, thanks very much.

**Edit:**

Error without Selenium-api.jar:
The import org.openqa cannot be resolved

Error with Selenium-api.jar:
The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: can you share the error log

Comment: @Obuli Sundar  Done :)

Comment: Normally if you want to use a library (normal jar) in eclipse plugin you have to use it by making it as a bundle.. then only the plugin can take the dependency. converth the selenium-api jar as bundle and use it in plugin.it will resolve the conflict

Comment: I have answered it with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin will accept only osgi bundles as dependecy.you can convert your dependency as bundle by using p2-maven-plugin.
 I have given the detailed description in my following answer.
[How to add jar Non-osgi jar files as dependency to eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383111/how-to-add-jar-non-osgi-jar-files-as-dependency-to-eclipse-plugin)