# How to add non-osgi jar dependencies while using tycho

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, osgi-bundle, tycho

I am building an eclipse plugin using tycho compiler and added most of the osgi dependencies using p2 repository. But, I also want to add many non-osgi jars in dependencies tag of pom. But It is not taking any dependencies from dependencies tag.
Here is my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>test</name>
  <groupId>com.test.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>  
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Mars</id>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>file:///E:/repo/eclipseRepo/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>generator</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tester</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.0</version>
       </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have tried using **target-platform-configuration** plugin , but I guess it also considers osgi jars only.
How can I add non-osgi jars in POM.xml?

Comment: Looks like I can't flag this because of the bounty, but have you taken a look at this nearly identical post: [How to add jar Non-osgi jar files as dependency to eclipse plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383111/how-to-add-jar-non-osgi-jar-files-as-dependency-to-eclipse-plugin)